# TFS 2015 OnPremise - Change default encoding for new files in brownser

Tags: visual-studio, encoding, tfs, character-encoding, tfs-2015

We have a installation of TFS 2015 on premise here and we are having a issue with new files created via web browser, all new files are created with UTF-8 encoding and generating this characters ���� in the code viewer.

the problem is solved while setting the enconding to 1252 via Visual Studio / Source Explorer.

Right click on the file -> advanced > properties -> general -> set encoding

How do i set the default encoding for new files created via browser in TFS 2015 online (on premise)?

**[EDIT]**
Step-by-step
Open Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015
Select Team Project, at the team project page, go to "Code", 
click at the "..." ,
"Add Files" (like the image below).

I have the issue if i have characters like "ã", ,"õ", "ç", "á", etc.

[Img1 - Creating file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s68T.png)

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tested on my side but cannot repro this issue. Could you please share the steps to reproduce the issue for troubleshoot? also provide the specific characters/strings if possible.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Open Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015, Select Team Project, at the team project page, go to "Code", click at the "..." and "Add Files" (like the image link on the post). I have the issue if i have characters like "ã", ,"õ", "ç", "á", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever, you can [Configure Version Control File Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/manage-file-types#configure-version-control-file-encoding) via Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio as you did.

However, you can try to enable **Auto-Select** option ( `View > Encoding > Auto-Select`.) if you are using IE. (The default settings in Internet Explorer 11 : **Unicode (UTF-8)** and **Left-to-right document**.). You can also select other  language encoding, go to `View > Encoding > More`. Select the language encoding, Then restart IE. See [Auto-select language encoding setting in Internet Explorer for details.](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/auto-select-language-encoding-setting-internet-explorer)

For Chrome browser, you can try changing the encoding via the extension [Set Character Encoding](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/set-character-encoding/bpojelgakakmcfmjfilgdlmhefphglae)

---

**UPDATE:**

I tested with the characters you provided with UTF-8 encoding, they displayed well, no garbage characters.

Please check if this article helps: [Checking HTTP Headers](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-headers-charset.en)

[image]

Comment: @no luck, even with the new encoding selected in IE the new file continues to be created with UTF-8.

Comment: @fabiodraschimorciani I tested with the characters you provided with UTF-8 encoding, they displayed well, no garbage characters. Have you set other things?